# The jquery load function is not working on my code. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just starting with jquery and have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("hello.txt #p1");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, it just responds by making my div become blank. When it should just be out putting text. The text file is located in the same file as the html document. I have it set to .php format for the code and the text file is .txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an educated guess based on the limited information presented.

The line

```
$("#div1").load("hello.txt #p1");
```

Break it apart:

- `load` is making an Ajax call to fetch "hello.txt".
- When the document is loaded, jQuery parses the document and looks for an element with an id of "p1". (that is what the #p1" is)
- That content is loaded into the element with the id of div1

My guess is that you do not have an element with the id of "p1" in your text file.

So either give an element an id of p1

```
<p id="p1">This is the new text to show.</p>
```

or drop the p1 so it is `.load("hello.txt");`

Comment: Thanks epascarello.  I did not see these.  I was to busy readying the comments.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").load("hello.txt #p1");
```

You are trying to load the content of `hello.txt`, extract the content of the element with `id="p1"`, and then display that.

The content of the file is this:

```
This is a text file.
```

It is not an HTML document. It doesn't have any elements (with the id `p1` or otherwise) so the content you are searching for cannot be found.

If you want to load the whole content, then remove `#p1` from the `load` string.